# Computing a puzzling expectation with random variables and vectors.

Tags: integration, expected-value, gaussian

Suppose the random variables $z_i $ are i.i.d. draw from the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, two vector $\mathbf{v}=(v_1, 0)^\top$, $v_1>0$, $\mathbf{w}=(w_1, w_2)^\top$, the inner angle between $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{w}$ is $\theta$, $\operatorname{1}$ stands for indicator function (i.e. the its footnote condition is satisfied, return 1 else 0).

How to calculate $\mathbb{E}[z_1 \operatorname{1}_{z_1v1> 0, z_1w_1+z_2w_2>0}]$ ?

I guess this can be solved via integral over the feasible region ?

Comment: I am not sure about the integrating range as there are three free variables (with some restriction) involved..

Comment: Hint: the random variables $z_1v_1$ and $z_1w_1+z_2w_2$ are jointly Gaussian. What is their covariance ? What is their joint PDF ? Then integrate over the first quadrant.

Comment: I tried polar integration to solve this, but I am not very sure about the integrating region of $\phi$, am I right ? $ \mathbb{E} [z_1 \operatorname{1}_{z_1v_1>0,  z_1w_1 + z_2w_2 > 0}] = \int_0^\infty  r \exp(-0.5 r^2) \operatorname{d}r \int_{-0.5\pi + \theta}^{0.5 \pi} \frac{1}{2\pi} r \cos(\phi) \operatorname{d} \phi $

Comment: I want to make use of the angle $\theta$, but it is quite confusing since the variables in vector $w$ seems to be matter..

Comment: You are not following my hint. If you calculate the covariance you will see what this has to do with that angle.